# How to change margin for first page of Bibliography Only

Tags: bibliographies, margins, geometry, apa-style, apa6

I need the top margin to be 2 inches on the first page of my Bibliography and all subsequent pages in the Bibliography to have 1 inch top margins. I am using BibTeX to manage my references and using `natbib` to format them in the `apa6` document class.

I know that the `geometry` package can specify new margins for a specific page (`\newgeometry{top=2in}`), but how can this be used for the Bibliography since it is  created all at once?

Not sure how to show a MWE since this would require a `.bib` file...

```
\documentclass[man,12pt,natbib]{apa6}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\refname}{REFERENCES}    % W/out this command, it is not all capital letters.
\setlength{\bibsep}{12pt}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{myreferences}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe use `\afterpage{\newgeometry{top=2in}}` right before `\printbibliography`? You'll need the `afterpage` package for this, though.

Comment: No luck, but I appreciate the suggestion using the afterpage package.

Comment: Don't change the margin. Change the format of the section title it is using to create the heading. You've not given a working example, so it is hard to be specific without a lot of work, but that is the way headings are usually 'dropped' on a page. The margins stay the same - they only look larger because the heading drops down the page.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue trying to reduce the top margin of my bibliography on all pages except for the first.

This is more of a workaround than a solution but it saved me a lot of time having tried multiple other suggestions online.

This will only be of use to some people if, like me, formatting the bibliography only becomes a concern when the rest of a document is written.

What I did was I copied the contents of the .bbl file generated by BibTeX into my .tex document and manually reducing vertical spacing at the points where page breaks occur using

```
\newpage
\vspace*{-0.5in}
```

or whatever distance you need. Remember to remove the `\bibliography{}` command once this is done.